# What are the best ways for creating galleries from images stored as entities?

Tags: 7, entities, media

I have a gallery attached to node that allowed tagging of single picture.
I used Field Collection for that job.

Now I need to display those images in different structure:

[image: Gallery formats]

User when creating a node may choose prefered display.

Also same types of displays may be used for display all images from all nodes.

Could someone give me any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can use the [Galleria](https://www.drupal.org/project/galleria) module in D7. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... allows users to create image galleries using the Galleria jQuery plugin, found on http://galleria.aino.se.
>
> There are several different approaches of using this module to create Galleria image galleries. The most typical and easiest way to do so is to use it as a field formatter for image or media fields. All images uploaded to such a configured field will then be displayed in a Galleria gallery.
>
> You can also use it in conjunction with the [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) module to build a gallery of image nodes, referenced by a 'Node reference' field; or you can use the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module to gather a list of images to display in a Galleria.

Comment: it's not free jQuery script? http://galleria.io/themes/

Comment: here http://drupal.org/project/galleria galleria is a contributed module, no need to see or find the free galleria jquery plugin.